# UWP App proc.Start() Unable to Find the File Specified C#

Tags: c#, uwp, process

I have been trying to make a UWP app using the latest Windows 10 SDK and the latest version of Visual Studio 2019 that can launch bat files, but whenever I try to launch the bat file using a `Process`, and error occurs when doing `proc.Start()`. The error is the following:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'
```

Currently, the code is using the `ms-appx` protocol, but I have tried granting the app filesystem access by editing the app manifest and granting permissions through settings and giving it the full path to no avail. Sometimes, if the full path is specified in one string (and not concatenated), it gives an `access denied` error, even if the filesystem access is granted to the app and the windows folder can be accessed by `Everyone`. Using the `ms-appx` protocol, all I get is `The system cannot find the file specified`. The error should be self-explanatory, but the same exact code has worked inside of a C# Windows Forms App, but not in the UWP C# app.

Below is my code using the `ms-appx` protocol:

```
string InstallPath = "ms-appx:///App/InstallDir"
string batDir = InstallPath + "/Binaries/Win64/";
Proc = new Process();
Proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = batDir;
Proc.StartInfo.FileName = batDir + "Launcher.bat";
Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
Proc.Start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` method does not work in UWP. UWP applications much run in a sandbox. For the sake of system stability, the access to other processes is not supported.

You could try to use `StorageFolder.GetFileAsync(String)` method with a parameter which is the same full path, and the method will return a `StorageFile` instance. But the same full path used in `Process.Start()` will cause a `Win32Exception`.

Comment: If starting processes doesn't work, would be inclined to suggest another way to run a bat file, or is that not possible. Thank you for this information.

Comment: As you said in the case, the `Process` class can work in **Windows Forms App**. You could use **Desktop Bridge** technology to package a **Windows Forms App**(run a bat file in the **Windows Forms App**) as a desktop extension component to your UWP app.

Comment: About the introducation of **Desktop Bridge** technology, you could refer to the [document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/desktop-bridge-8211-the-bridge-between-desktop-apps-and-the/ba-p/316488). About the detailed steps of **Desktop Bridge** technology, you could refer to the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-extend#first-setup-your-solution) or a blog named **UWP with Desktop Extension – Part 1** of **Stefan Wick**.